# serializing data to a std::streambuf

Tags: c++, serialization, iostream, streambuf

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project where I'm trying to serialize data from several classes to a custom `std::streambuf` implementation.

The data classes with their serialization:

```
struct Header { /*...*/ };

inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Header& h ) 
{ 
    /* serialize the members of Header here */
    os.write( h.some_member, sizeof( h.some_member ) );
    return os;
}

struct Info { /*...*/ };

inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Info& i ) 
{ 
    /* serialize the members of Info here */
    return os;
}
```

The streambuffer implementation provides buffered i/o and overrides `underflow` and `overflow`.

```
class MyStreamBuf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    MyStreamBuf() { InitBuffers(); };

private:

    void InitBuffers()
    {
        recv_buffer_.resize( buff_size );
        send_buffer_.resize( buff_size );
        setg( &recv_buffer_[ 0 ], &recv_buffer_[ 0 ], &recv_buffer_[ 0 ] );
        setp( &send_buffer_[ 0 ], &send_buffer_[ 0 ] );
    };

    enum { buff_size = 512 };

    std::vector< char_type > recv_buffer_;
    std::vector< char_type > send_buffer_;

    int_type underflow() { /* ... */ };

    int_type overflow( char_type c )
    {
        *pptr() = c;
        pbump( 1 );
        // if the buffer is full, flush the data
        if( pptr() == epptr() )
            flush();
        return c;
    };

    void flush()
    {
        std::ptrdiff_t n = pptr() - pbase();
        int written = /* send n bytes to the data destination */
        pbump( -written );
    };
}; // class MyStreamBuf
```

My intended usage is something like this:

```
Header h( /* some useful info */ );
Info i( /* some useful info */ );

MyStreamBuf dest;
std::iostream my_stream( &dest );
dest << h << i; // MyStreambuf::overflow() is never called!
```

But, `MyStreambuf::overflow` is never called. What do I need to do to get the data to my buffer?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `flush()` on the iostream (or call `pubsync()` on your streambuf).

Traditionally you'd do this in the destructor of your streambuf (in the same way that filebuf's destructor calls `close()`), in which case you just need to destroy it.

Also it's conventional to provide a class inheriting from iostream that owns an instance of your streambuf and ensures it is flushed/destroyed when appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Also, my `setp()` is wrong, but that didn't affect the answer directly.